# Apollo Client Query Deduplication on Cached Object

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I recently read an article about Apollo Client Caching on the [official blog](https://blog.apollographql.com/the-concepts-of-graphql-bc68bd819be3), with a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obH1Y.png)
here.

According to the article, if the current query contains a cached object, along with other objects, the query will be deduplicated to only query the rest of the objects.

However, I did some testing by logging out queries on the server, which suggested that the query had not been partially deduplicated. Instead, the entire query got sent to the server.

Can anyone provide any insight on this. Thanks very much.

**Test**:

First query:

```
{
   post(_id: 1) {
      _id
      title
   }
}
```

Second query:

```
{
   post(_id: 1) {
      _id
      title
   }
   author(_id: 1) {
      _id
      firstName
   }
}
```

**Intended outcome:**
The secomd query received by the server only contains

```
author(_id: 1) {
   _id
   firstName
}
```

since `post(_id: 1)` has been cached after the first query is sent, according to the blog.

**Actual outcome:**
Server log: (the second query has **NOT** been deduplicated)

```
{
   "operationName": null,
   "variables": {},
   "query": "{\n  post(_id: 1) {\n    _id\n    title\n    __typename\n  
   }\n}\n"
} /graphql 200 81 - 0.520 ms

{
   "operationName": null,
   "variables": {},
   "query": "{\n  post(_id: 1) {\n    _id\n    title\n    __typename\n  
   }\n  author(_id: 1) {\n    _id\n    firstName\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
} /graphql 200 140 - 0.726 ms
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a subject called `Query deduplication` in `Apollo-Client`
that comes from `Apollo-Link` (the transport layer of `Apollo-Client`)
but what it does is deduplicate existing queries that are currently being fetched

> Query deduplication can be useful if many components display the same data, but you don’t want to fetch that data from the server many times. It works by comparing a query to all queries **currently in flight**

you can read more about it [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/network-layer.html#query-deduplication) and [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-dedup)

But it doesn't relate so much to the cache..
 I think what you're looking for is a better understanding of how cache is managed in `Apollo-Client`

So how is caching handled in `Apollo-Client`?
 you can find a more through article about it here from their official docs: [apollo-client-caching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html)


more specifically to your case i believe that if you would use [watchQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.watchQuery) / [query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.query) and make sure the `fetchPolicy` is `cache-first` then it might not resend the query

I hope this gives you better insight on caching in `Apollo-Client`